# SNES Super Picross - Mario SP-I

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, nonogram

Currently stuck on Super Picross and looking for a hint for the next logical deduction on Mario stage SP-I.

[image: Mario stage SP-I]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A deduction for either side column:

> The second-from side columns can have runs of maximum length 2. Therefore, the 5 and 3 on the side columns must use a row which has an ending run of length 1. For the 3, this may happen anywhere. For the 5, there must be 1s in sufficient places such that no 3-length section of the 5 passes through rows which all have starting runs of length >1.

For example:

> If the leftmost-column's run of 5 is placed in the top of the un-Xed place (rows 3-8), each of the rows it passes through have a starting run of length >1. Therefore each row will extend a run out of the 5, moving to columns further right. However, since all rows extend, the second-from-left column will have a run of 5, which is not allowed.

This gets you to:

> [image: Hint]

If you need a little further, try applying similar logic to:

> the top row

with the important modification that

> only columns with length >2 need be considered bad, and now it is runs of 4 bad columns which are disallowed.

Comment: If this isn't far enough, Sam, please tell me and I'll delete it

Comment: It’s good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

> You can determine the position of the 7 in the second row.

Where?

> [image: hint]

Why? Otherwise, we can deduce the following sequence.

First,

> [image: first deduction]

Then,

> [image: second deduction]

Finally,

> [image: third deduction]

However,

> this creates a group of 4 in the third row.